# How to move a file from a model's folder to another?

Tags: python, django, file, django-models, django-views

I have two models [1] `TempFile(models.Model)` and `Company(models.Model)` , when the view [2] `save_records(request)` is called I'd like to **save & move** the image from `TempFile(models.Model)` which is in folder `/temporary_files/` **to** `Company(models.Model)` which is in folder `/company_logo/`.

[1] **models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to="company_logo")
    ...

class TempFile(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="temporary_files")
    ...
```

[2] **views.py**

```
def save_records(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        temp_file = TempFile.objects.get(unique_id=request.session['uuid'])

        Company.objects.create(
            logo = temp_file.image
            ...
        )
```

Here's the problem with this method, while the `logo` is saved the path of the folder stays `/temporary_files/`. I'd like to know how to save or move the image without quality loss and performance issue to `Company(models.Model)`'s `company_logo` folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using file system storage, then the most efficient option is to move the file on disk (see [this part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/files/#using-files-in-models)):

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

temp_file = TempFile.objects.get(unique_id=request.session['uuid'])

# Move the file
old_path = temp_file.image.path
filename = os.path.basename(old_path)
new_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'company_logo', filename)
os.rename(old_path, new_path)
temp_file.save()

Company.objects.create(
    logo = temp_file.image
)
```

Note that the path of `temp_file.image` has also changed - presumably you will be deleting that object once you've saved the `Company` object.